# Получить ссылку страницы сайта, переделать её и вывести

Tags: php, javascript

Сайт имеет несколько локализаций: ru и en.

Как сделать так - если пользователь находится на странице http://site.com/sample.html
что бы на этой странице выводилась ссылочка на другой язык этой страницы http://site.com/en/sample.html
И эта ссылка менялась в зависимости от страницы на которой пользователь находится.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чуть подправил [ответ Samuel Loog](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/603973/) и вышло так. Рабочий вариант проверил. Спасибо, без вас сам бы не смог.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('download');
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var host = window.location.host;
    if (path.substring(0,4) == '/ua/'){
        newpath = path.substring(3);
        var val = 'Рус';
    } else {
        newpath = '/ua' + path;
        var val = 'Укр';
    }
    a.href = newpath;
    a.text = val;
}
</script>
```

Comment: а чем ваш ответ отличается от ответа @SamuelLong кроме того, как у вас `/ua` вместо `/en`?)

Comment: Прошу обратить внимание на формирование ссылки, строчки 7 и 10.

Comment: Проблема, скорее всего в том, что я написал ответ с расчётом на абсолютные ссылки, а в вашем случае, предположу, используются относительные. В вопросе об этом ни слова, к тому же пример приведёт с абсолютными ссылками.

Comment: Я ни в коем случае не критикую Ваш ответ, без Вашего ответа ничего бы не вышло, огромное спасибо. Он был то что надо, только чуточку подправить, что бы правильно формировалась ссылка.

Comment: @Андрей у нас принято отмечать галкой тот ответ, который вам помог (который стал основой для вашего решения) как благодарность отвечающему.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ поправлен после уточнения вопроса.

На все страницы добавляем:

```
<a href='#' id='download'></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('download');
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var host = window.location.host;
    if (path.substring(0,4) == '/en/'){
        newpath = host + path.substring(3);
        var val = 'Рус';
    } else {
        newpath = host + '/en' + path;
        var val = 'En';
    }
    a.href = newpath;
    a.text = val;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, но совсем не то :). Страниц на сайте около 3 тыс. ссылка должна меняться динамически в зависимости от страницы. Скорее всего имеет смысл определять урл страницы, изменять его и уже потом выводить с подставкой "/en/" или удалять этот "en" с выводимого урла.

Comment: Тогда стоит уточнить Ваш вопрос :)

Comment: Думал сделать через document.location.href но что-то запнулся. Может будут идеи реализации?

Comment: Тогда, как вариант, js: `window.location.host` - даст вам `site.com`, а `window.location.pathname` даст вам `/path/to/sample.html`. берем первое + /en + второе -- получаем нужный адрес. Если же второе начинается с /en/, то, наоборот, обрезаем и опять получаем нужный линк

Comment: На страницу при генерации в нужном месте вешаем ссылку `<a href='#' id='lang'></a>`, далее при загрузке страницы js получает её адрес, по id получает элемент ссылки, парсим адрес страницы, вставляем ссылку(это всё, если делать через js. Можно ещё со стороны сервера это всё сделать при генерации страницы, но это зависит от того, что вы используете.)

Comment: Спасибо. Прошу напишите пожалуйста реализованный код (который нужно просто вставить на сайт), я в js очень плох.

Comment: @Андрей Исправил ответ. Код проверил только ту часть, что внутри функции `window.onload` -- он работает. По идее функция должна отработать после загрузки страницы

Comment: Спасибо, но чуть чуть не получилось. Теперь ссылка стала на En версии стала иметь вид - http://site.ru/en/site.ru/price_discount.html

Comment: Вообще забавная ситуация вышла с «собственным» ответом автора. Он декларирует, что ему нужно ru и en, а на самом деле нужно ru и ua. И к чему была вот эта маскировка? ))